# Updating a mySQL trigger Timestamp field with a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create an trigger to a table I have customers. Simply I want to update a field editchange (Timestamp) to the current date time after the table has changed (just the one row). Everything I try is getting an error message.

Could someone please point me in the right direction with a bit of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define direct a field (timestamp) that they update the time, so you not neet a Trigger

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vals` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `change` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I tried to change the table with the following:    ALTER TABLE `customers`
MODIFY COLUMN `editchange`  datetime NULL DEFAULT 'timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' AFTER `mutipleinvoiceonorders`;

but I got an error message saying it was an invalid value

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You can it only use on the same table. So when you write on Table customers it  can be set the timestamp to now().

Comment: I am using it on the same table

Comment: then this must be ok:

ALTER TABLE customers MODIFY editchange DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Comment: Here is what I got:   [SQL] ALTER TABLE customers MODIFY editchange DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
[Err] 1067 - Invalid default value for 'editchange'

Comment: Post result from  DESC customers;

Comment: got to be in 2 parts to keep this website happy

Comment: Its a long table so I will have to break it down further

Comment: Reference int(11) Auto Increment
   company varchar(50) Allow Null
   name varchar(50) Allow Null
   address1 varchar(50) Allow Null
   address2 varchar(50) Allow Null
   address3 varchar(50) Allow Null
   city varchar(30) Allow Null
   CountryState varchar(30) Allow Null
   postcode varchar(20) Allow Null
   country int(11) Allow Null
   IDStatus int(11) Allow Null
   phone varchar(30) Allow Null
   fax varchar(30) Allow Null
   MobilePhone varchar(30) Allow Null
   Salutation varchar(30) Allow Nu

Comment: title varchar(130) Allow Null
   firstname varchar(20) Allow Null
   Lastname varchar(20) Allow Null
   WebsiteURL varchar(50) Allow Null
   email varchar(60) Allow Null
   DateEntry datetime Allow Null
   category double Allow Null
   owner int(20) Allow Null
   Notes longtext Allow Null
   county varchar(30) Allow Null
   USState int(11) Allow Null
   internalcompany int(11) Allow Null
   cleaned int(11) Allow Null
   recomenddelete int(11) Allow Null
   hold int(11) Allow Null
   tocheck int(11) Allow Null
   hasordered int(11) Allow Null

Comment: cash int(11) Allow Null
   cashrelease date Allow Null
   cashreleaseby int(11) Allow Null
   cashreleasenote longtext Allow Null
   placedonholddate date Allow Null
   archive int(11) Allow Null
   mutipleinvoiceonorders int(11) Allow Null
   editchange datetime Allow Null

Comment: Thanks for sending the details, but i cant find a timestamp field or a field named change. Can you please tell wich field you want to update ?

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in my copying. The field editchange is a timestamp fields